# Golang function to return a postgres select result, then scan it in another function

Tags: sql, postgresql, function, go

I have a function which connects to a postgres database and selects from a table but i dont want
to use that data in the same function. What i want is to return the queryResult object and pass it to another function which should then execute the queryResult.Next() function to get the rows.

Here is what i have tried but it returns empty queryResult. When I call queryResult.Next(), I check to see whether the loop runs atleast once, and I realise that it never even enters the loop.

```golang
func dbconnect() *sql.DB {
    //url := "postgres://qkwgasaecyvmmh:7f0acdb20c3446d07e52c125aff4568d43593d62e864bb00291d1688ecd057dc@ec2-50-17-197-184.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/d1oqfcb0uf7on4"
    //connection, _ := pq.ParseURL(url)
    connection := fmt.Sprintf("host=%s port=%d user=%s password=%s dbname=%s", host, port, user, password, dbname)
    connection += " sslmode=disable"

    db, err := sql.Open("postgres", connection)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
    }else{
        log.Println("Connected to postgres db.") 
    }
    return db
}

//------------
    
func retreiveAllResponses() *sql.Rows {
    db := dbconnect()
    defer db.Close()
    //retrieve all responses. 
    selecQuery := fmt.Sprintf("SELECT OrgResponseData FROM responses;")
    queryResult, err := db.Query(selecQuery)
    defer queryResult.Close()
    if err != nil {  
        fmt.Println(err.Error())
    }  
     
    return queryResult;
 }

//-----------------
    noResponsesYet := true 
    for queryResult.Next(){
        //stream each response to the client
        log.Println(" --> queryResult.Next loop executing ...")
        var OrgResponseData string  
        _ = queryResult.Scan(&OrgResponseData) 
       noResponsesYet = false
    }
```

I am sure that the database table has some data whuch I expect to be returned.

By the way, this was working fine in MySQL but when I switched to postgres it failed.

Comment: You're closing the rows upon exit with `defer queryResult.Close()`. The caller handling the result should be responsible for closing it.

Comment: `defer db.Close()` is probably not helping either.

Comment: Also, you should stop invoking `defer x.Close()` *before* checking the `err` and, of course, exit if `err` is not `nil`, unless you want your program to panic, in which case you can keep doing whatever you like.